# Верстка через javascript

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, css

Последнее время, все чаще приходит в голову, что сверстать что-то кроссбраузерно можно только переменив js(например многоблочная, div-овая, резиновая верстка). Может быть уже существуют js фреймворки для подобных костылей с версткой?

*Это конечно большее фантазии.*

Comment: Это очень жетокий вопрос, что значит JS - фреймворки для вёрстки?Вы хоть что-нибудь верстали на JS? Я - нет, только для помощи подключал jQuery, остальное всё делается на HTML/CSS. А костыли эти: jQuery, YUI, Mootools, Prototype.

Comment: Совершенно недопустимо использовать js костыли для верстки, тем более "верстать" с помощью js, лучше подтяните свои знания в цсс.

Comment: Ну вот кстати, если разрабатывается пиложение, которое болт клало на поисковики, с кучей кнопочек-свистелок, то почему бы и нет? Намного большей гибкости можно достичь, чем если полагаться на браузерные плюшки, даже если все с `position: absolute;` и пересчетеом на onScroll и onResize. Плюсанул и жду ответа)

Comment: а чем вам в качестве кросбраузерного и кросплатформенного html/css фрейворка [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) не угодил?

Comment: В начальном виде можно даже сохранить семантику и возможность проиндексировать. А когда уже весь js догрузится то перестроить страницу. Вон @Sh4dow понял затею правильно, иногда красивых и простых и главное кроссбраузерных css/html решений просто нет, особенно если не использовать таблицы=)) К сожалению погуглив 20 минут я ничего пока не нашел.

Comment: bootstrap сложное некрасивое решение?...абсурд! и он использует именно, цитирую "...многоблочная, div-овая, резиновая верстка...", без таблиц, рекомендую ознакомится по-лучше с сабжем

Comment: @Spectre бутстрап то мне как раз угодил, но не все можно сделать на нем, ой далеко не все. Например сверстать промо, оно явно не для этого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не только я об этом думал http://habrahabr.ru/post/167525/

Answer (score 4):

Степень затруднений, испытываемых при достижении переносимости прямо зависит от сложности верстки. То есть для наиболее простых случаев, вполне можно написать одинаковый HTML + CSS для всех браузеров, а для более сложных случаев может потребоваться и JS.

Универсальной библиотеки, при подключении которой движки браузеров начинают вести себя одинаково не встречалось, а отдельные скрипты, которые что-то исправляют по частям, есть.

- [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) - воздействует на IE так, что он начинает удовлетворять многим стандартам.
- [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) - включает поддержку HTML5 в IE.
- [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) - включают поддержку частей HTML5 в разные браузеры.

Comment: Неплохие костыли, спасибо, попробую применить.